# REST API error while posting a customized Priority fields

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I'm trying to post REST API of the ORDERS form.
I have added a few customized fields to the sub form PAYMENTDEF in order to post all the credit cards information.

I'm getting the error:

> 'An error has occurred'

any time I'm posting the customized fields, if I remove them from the request I managed to post.

```
{"CUSTNAME":"5","CDES":"רועי בן מנחם","CURDATE":"2018-07-18","BOOKNUM":"2164","SHIPTO2_SUBFORM":{"NAME":"רועי בן מנחם","PHONENUM":"0507573753","ADDRESS":"דן 4","STATE":"שערי תקווה","COUNTRYNAME":"Israel","ZIP":"44810","ADDRESS2":"44"},"ORDERITEMS_SUBFORM":[{"PARTNAME":"CLEAN0044","TQUANT":1,"PRICE":19.9,"REMARK1":"","ROYY_ORDISPECS_SUBFORM":[]},{"PARTNAME":"000","TQUANT":1,"PRICE":30,"REMARK1":""}],"PAYMENTDEF_SUBFORM":{"PAYMENTCODE":"3","QPRICE":53.28,"PAYACCOUNT":"1234","PAYCODE":"","VALIDMONTH":"0124","CCUID":"123456789","CONFNUM":"09090909","ROYY_NUMBEROFPAY":"","FIRSTPAY":"","ROYY_SECONDPAYMENT":""}}
```

And this is my header:
   https://pri.officeandmore.co.il/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/tirgul2/ORDERS

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Appears to have something to do with payment, however you are not giving any details about it. Plus the link is not visitable. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try check if these fields are visible in the REST api service:

Request the service [metadata](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/request/#Requesting_the_Service_Metadata) as following:

https://pri.officeandmore.co.il/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/tirgul2/$metadata

In the result check for the `PAYMENTDEF` subform's metadata (search for `<EntityType Name="PAYMENTDEF">` and check if your customized fields appear in the property (field) list.

If they don't appear, probably these fields are set as 'hidden fields' in the 'Priority form' or that you have permission limitations.

If they do appear, the problem is probably related to incorrect values you are trying to post to these fields. Take a look in the metadata result to see the expected values format for each of these fields.